# OleDbConnection UPDATE Syntax Error, SQL work but won't update DataBase

Tags: c#, syntax-error, oledb, oledbconnection

Here is sample code:
Everything else works but keep getting syntax update error?
SQL checked and does work as an SQL query outside.

```
    public bool changes()
    {


        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

        string myQuery = "UPDATE Login SET Pass='" + textBox1.Text + "' WHERE User='" + textBox2.Text + "'";

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using and print the `myQuery` variable and see what it's prints

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 :   using: Database.accdb type file which is a Local File. 

Upon Debugging get correct vales for  Update, but once it Hits ExecuteNonQuery() method it goes straight to catching exception ex.

No Database connection issues and field and database name is correct in the SQL.

Comment: What are the details of the exception?

Comment: Thrown: "Syntax error in UPDATE statement." (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException) Exception Message = "Syntax error in UPDATE statement.", Exception Type = "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException"


MyQuery output: UPDATE Login SET Pass='password' WHERE User='Sam"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's because of your `WHERE` part as shown below. `User` is a [reserve word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) in MS Access and thus needs to be escaped using `[]` like

```
WHERE [User]='" + textBox2.Text + "'"
```

Also your current approach is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Instead use parameterized query as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This makes sense. Poor choice of field name. However, he mentioned he was able to run the query manually...

Comment: @Juan, that's a mistake made probably by OP while posting. Cause his posted query won't even run when run manually.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't type the remaining word here so I used where = Username. That's how I was able to run it.

Comment: So I finally got it to work, Just  escaped using [] on all Fields on the table.
Many Thanks.  for such a  simple advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters instead of concatenating the values in a string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a code sample with the **using** statement (as someone else recommended, for proper disposing of resources):

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: The query appears sound. It looks to me like the reason it doesn't work is that the inputs must contain characters that are causing errors with the driver (as the query works on the outside). I am more than happy to make it a comment but it seems to me like he has a question (why it doesn't work) and I provided an answer (because you are concatenating strings instead of using parameters). Let me know why you think it should be a comment. If you have a compelling argument, I will make it one.

Comment: Removed comment as now your edit adds value. But that's not the real issue here. See my answer.

Comment: I added that, Parameters to the code. Still ends up with the same Syntax. Oh LORD. Driving me up the Wall.